# Sending XML as a string param in WCF from ios

Tags: ios, xml, wcf

I have a WCF method that looks like this:

.NET
    void doSomething(string data)

in iOS

I call this method passing data as XML:

```
NSString *data = plistXMLContent;
```

Do I need to escape this or encode this?  when I hard code data=@"hello";

it makes it to the WCF. but not when data=xml for example:

```
data="< data >hello< / data >"; does to make it to the WCF.
```

any suggestions?

don't mind the space in the element tag. I didn't know how to make it show in the post.

Comment: Have you tried to trace WCF service logs to trace issue, are you getting any error ?

Comment: Does service accepts data in XML format? If it is so, then it should work because data=@"hello" is a simple string while other one is XML.

Comment: Is your iOS app using JavaScript or JSON to send the request? If so, I might be able to help, but otherwise I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Placed it inside a CDATA tag fixed the problem.